# Changing quantity with + and - buttons on Woocommerce using Elementor, when plus and minus buttons are not a part of the cart form

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I am using elementor with woocommerce. The use of custom hooks is not possible.

I want to separate my plus and minus buttons away from the quantity input because of the page design.

I have got the following code to display the buttons on the single_product page, but the plus/minus buttons don't change the quantity. I guess this is because they are placed outside of the actual form. I don't know enough jquery to understand what I need to change.

Any help would be appreciated:

(First of all: Credit to the author. The code is borrowed from https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-plus-minus-buttons-to-add-to-cart-quantity-input/ and this code works beatifully, but then I moved it to another hook that better suits my needs, outside the form...)

#1: DISPLAY THE BUTTONS:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'bbloomer_display_quantity_plus' );
  
function bbloomer_display_quantity_plus() {
   echo '<div class="plusminusbuttons"><button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>';
   echo '<button type="button" class="plus" >+</button></div>';

}
```

#2 TRIGGER THE jQuery Script

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'bbloomer_add_cart_quantity_plus_minus' );
  
function bbloomer_add_cart_quantity_plus_minus() {
   // Only run this on the single product page
   if ( ! is_product() ) return;
   ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
           
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){   
           
         $('form.cart').on( 'click', 'button.plus, button.minus', function() {
  
            // Get current quantity values
            var qty = $( this ).closest( 'form.cart' ).find( '.qty' );
            var val   = parseFloat(qty.val());
            var max = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'max' ));
            var min = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'min' ));
            var step = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'step' ));
  
            // Change the value if plus or minus
            if ( $( this ).is( '.plus' ) ) {
               if ( max && ( max <= val ) ) {
                  qty.val( max );
               } else {
                  qty.val( val + step );
               }
            } else {
               if ( min && ( min >= val ) ) {
                  qty.val( min );
               } else if ( val > 1 ) {
                  qty.val( val - step );
               }
            }
              
         });
           
      });
           
      </script>
```

**Edit**

My html look like this

```
<div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-add-to-cart elementor-product-simple">        
        <div class="plusminusbuttons"><button type="button" class="minus">-</button><button type="button" class="plus">+</button>
        </div>
    
        <form class="cart" action="https://www.mydomain.no/product/sunglasses" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="quantity">
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5ff35879156fb">Sunglasses quantity</label>
            <input type="number" id="quantity_5ff35879156fb" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
            </div>
    
            <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="20" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `.cart` and `.qty` ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I would say you need to replace form.cart with the selector that contains button.plus and  button.minus.

```
<div class="outside-the-form">
  <form class="cart">
    <div class="qty">

$('.plusminusbuttons').on( 'click', 'button.plus, button.minus', function() {
  
// Get current quantity values
var qty = $( this ).closest( '.elementor-add-to-cart' ).find( '.qty' );
```

Comment: I tried setting your "outside-the-form" as my "plusminusbuttons", but that did not work. Any other ideas, after seing my html?

Comment: I updated the code based on your HTML. This should work.